# How to figure out memory leak in node process

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-dump

My nodejs application is leaking memory, so I was trying to use heapdump to compare the memory changes, unfortunately, memory does not change in headdump, but my nodejs process is leaking memory.So I was thinking native-modules could be one culprit, then I was using mtrace to figure it out. 
But I could not understand Module "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6" is increasing the size.

Does anyone could help give me some suggestions of tools or ways to figure out memory leak that does not happens in heap itself.

Many appreciate.

Comment: Here's great article about it that helped me https://www.nearform.com/blog/self-detect-memory-leak-node/

Comment: Already tried to use, won't help, thanks anyone

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to start your node.js application with a restricted amount of heap memory (--max_old_space_size=100 for example) and wait for an out of memory to happen.

If it happens, install [node-oom-heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oom-heapdump) and start the process again. When it goes out of memory now, a heapdump is automatically generated, showing you the culprit.
It it doesn't happen, there is no memory leak.

The reason your heapdump is not showing a rise is probably because of the garbage collector; before a heapdump is made, the garbage collector kicks in. 
So i'm not sure you actually have a leak; if a garbage collect fixes the heap usage, there is no leaking.